# GPG error: https://cli.github.com/packages stable InRelease: EXPKEYSIG C99B11DEB97541F0

Tags: linux, git, repository, github-cli

Trying to update the GitHub CLI with the apt package manager fails with this error:

```bash
Failed to fetch https://cli.github.com/packages/dists/stable/InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: EXPKEYSIG C99B11DEB97541F0
GPG error: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG C99B11DEB97541F0
```

Answer (score 47):

You're seeing this error because the issuer of this certificate (https://github.com/vilmibm) has allowed it to expire. They've [stated](https://github.com/cli/cli/issues/6175#issuecomment-1235984381) that this may not be fixed soon, or at all. Your options are:

1. Wait for the certificate to be renewed, so that everything will go back to normal.
2. Ignore the error and install the package anyway with `sudo apt install gh --allow-unauthenticated` (note this is not a good idea from a security standpoint)
3. Download [the latest release](https://github.com/cli/cli/releases/latest) and install manually instead of using apt. If you do this you should also remove the source from your packages list so that you won't see the error on update: `sudo apt-key del C99B11DEB97541F0 && sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/github-cli.list`

**Update 2022-09-07:**

A new certificate has now been issued for this package. As per answers from FourDollars and Adam Sherwood below, you can fix/update by following [these instructions](https://github.com/cli/cli/blob/trunk/docs/install_linux.md).

Answer (score 37):

You can run the following commands again to fix the GPG error.

```
curl -fsSL https://cli.github.com/packages/githubcli-archive-keyring.gpg | sudo dd of=/usr/share/keyrings/githubcli-archive-keyring.gpg \
&& sudo chmod go+r /usr/share/keyrings/githubcli-archive-keyring.gpg \
&& echo "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/githubcli-archive-keyring.gpg] https://cli.github.com/packages stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/github-cli.list > /dev/null \
&& sudo apt update \
&& sudo apt install gh -y
```

It is noted on https://github.com/cli/cli/blob/trunk/docs/install_linux.md#debian-ubuntu-linux-raspberry-pi-os-apt.

Answer (score 4):

I am currently running Pop_os (20.04) and had to do the following (note: the first two lines were undoing the previous attempt to use the new accepted method in the docs):

```bash
sudo rm /usr/share/keyrings/githubcli-archive-keyring.gpg \
&& sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/github-cli.list \
&& sudo apt-key del C99B11DEB97541F0 \
&& sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key 23F3D4EA75716059 \
&& sudo apt-add-repository https://cli.github.com/packages \
&& sudo apt install gh -y
```

Source: https://github.com/cli/cli/issues/5810#issuecomment-1240200365